# SQL Database Engine Tuning Advisor returns recommendations but Tuning Log is empty

Tags: sql-server, database-tuning-advisor

Please can someone explain to me why the tuning log returns no results even though the tuning advisor suggests lots of recommendations?! I'm new to this tool so think there is something obvious that I'm missing.

Many thanks in advance for your advice :)